# What does the "Coverage" mean in Xcode's build settings under Preprocessor Macros

Tags: xcode, macros, preprocessor, code-coverage

Click any target --> build settings --> Preprocessor Macros --> Coverage

BTW, any books or materials talks everything about Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Coverage shows which parts of your code are tested by unit tests. With coverage you can find out where you need to write more tests to make sure that your critical code parts are actually tested by your tests. Have a look at this article for more details on what coverage does and how to set it up in XCode: http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-code-coverage/